# C# / RegEx - Modify Lines in Text File

Tags: c#, regex

I have a large text file that I need to check line by line and modify accordingly. What I'm looking for is lines that start with DTP*348*D8*yyyymmdd (yyyymmdd will be populated with actual dates in the file).  If the line falls between the lines REF*1L*0002 and REF*1L*0011 I want all dates prior to 20140601 to be changed to 20140601 (any dates later than 20140601 should be left alone).  So DTP*348*D8*20090605 would become DTP*348*D8*20140601.

Lines between REF*1L*0011 and REF*1L*0030 I would like dates prior to 20140701 to be changed to 20140701 and anything later to be left alone.  So DTP*348*D8*20140605 would become DTP*348*D8*20140701.

The line REF*1L*xxxx lines occur multiple times throughout the file, but they are not mixed up.  For instance, once the first instance of REF*1L*0011 is reached, REF*1L*0002 will no longer appear in the file and once the line REF*1L*0030 is reached, neither REF*1L*0002 nor REF*1L*0011 will appear again in the file.

I just confused myself with all that.  Hopefully it makes some sense!

EDIT:  Here is an example of the file contents.

```
REF*1L*0002
REF*DX*100A
REF*ZZ*00
DTP*336*D8*19990816
NM1*IL*1*XXXX*XXXXX****34*XXXXXXXX
PER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXXX
N3*XXXXX XXXXX XXX
N4*XXXXX*XX*XXXXX
DMG*D8*19760910*F*I
HD*030**HLT*0002XXX01*XXX
DTP*348*D8*20150601 (*This is the line I want to edit*)
INS*N*19*030**A
REF*0F*XXXXXX
REF*1L*0011
```

(The rest of the file contains lines similar to the above, repeating).  The type of file I'm working with is called an [EDI 834](https://www.1edisource.com/transaction-sets?tset=834) if that helps.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I accomplish what I described above using C# Regex.Replace?  (I'm assuming that's what I would use, unless there is a better way).

For instance, I'm using a similar approach on a less complicated file:

`File.WriteAllText(fn, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(fn), @"DTP\*348\*D8\*201[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", "DTP*348*D8*20150701"));`

Comment: Can you provide a sample file in your question, so we can see the format of the lines?

Comment: Let me get an example together.  I'll have to strip out some info.

Comment: Is there a way I can upload a screen shot?  I tried pasting some lines from the file and they come out all jacked up in the comment.

Comment: Add it as a "code block" and it should keep its format.

Comment: No luck, it's still running together as one consecutive line. Just to be sure I'm doing it correctly, enclosing the as `code` (where "code" is the text) is how to add a code block?

Comment: You're adding it correctly, you probably have to add line breaks where necessary.

Comment: Thanks!  I just added a sample to the original question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you only concerned with the line you marked `DTP*348*D8*20150601`, or the top `DTP` segment as well `DTP*336*D8*19990816`??

Comment: @dubstylee Only the `DTP*348*D8*xxxxxxxx` segments, everything else will be left alone. Also, if it helps, the only `REF*1L*xxxx` segments will be `REF*1L*0002, REF*1L*0011 and REF*1L*0030`.  There won't be any in between like 0003, 0012, etc.

Comment: Also, is there a requirement to use `Regex`?  If not, then you could easily iterate through the file line by line and then process only the necessary data...

Comment: Not necessarily a requirement to use `Regex`, I just assumed that would be the way to go.  My end goal is to automate iterating through the file and making the changes while leaving the formatting of the file intact.  I'm open to any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not proficient enough in regular expressions to try to help you achieve it that way, but since you said that is not a requirement, here is a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N1u8ot) that accomplishes what you are trying to do.

Basically, it loops through one line at a time, if it hits a line that begins with `DTP*348` then it will parse out the date.  If the date is less than 20140601, it will replace the date with 20140601.

The example just uses static text, but you can easily adapt the concept to reading in a text file and writing back to the text file.

Comment: I'm getting an error after modifying the code.  Since you've already answered this question, should I create a new question with the code issue?  Not sure how things are usually done on this site :-)

Comment: Did you get it figured out?  Let me know if you are still having trouble and I will try to help.

Comment: Yes, it was a trailing \r in the file at the end of the `DTP` segment.  Caught it in Notepad++.  I do have one more modification I'd like to make and if you can help me with that it would be awesome.  How do I change the criteria for the date in the `DTP` segment once I hit `REF*1L*0011` in the file?  Let me know if you want me to post this as a new question and I will.  Thanks again!

Comment: Will you be changing the date still, or just leaving them alone after the `REF*1L*0011` line?

Comment: Once we hit `REF*1L*0011` I want to change dates prior to 20140701 to 20140701.  At some point later in the file, we'll hit `REF*1L*0030` but I don't want to change any of those dates.  Here is the Fiddle of what I have so far https://dotnetfiddle.net/1y3Uz8

Comment: Alright, I made some minor changes to your fiddle so that after `REF*1L*0011` it will change dates prior to 20140701, and after `REF*1L*0030` it will leave the dates alone. Try this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/shU4us

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much for your help!  I wish I could mark your comment as an answer LOL.

Comment: Haha, well I'm sure that the fiddle isn't necessarily the best/easiest/most efficient way to accomplish your task, but it should be good enough for what you are looking to do.

Comment: As long as it gets the job done, that's all I care about!  Thanks again.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

About the date you can use this

```
File.WriteAllText(fn, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(fn), 
    @"(201[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|2014[0-6][0-9][0-9][0-9])", 
    "20140701"));
```

Not clear what is the range REF*1L*0011 to REF*1L*0030. If need to include all numbers from 0011 to 0030 the regular expression is

```
REF\*1L\*(001[1-9]|002[0-9]|0030)
```

Comment: The question is only referring to the date in the `DTP` segment, I think.

Comment: @dubstylee Yes, that's the only segment I want to modify (if necessary).